# how to change char * to Go equivalent

Tags: c, go

I have some c code that look like this-

```
*((Oid *) ((char *)(tup)
```

where Oid is a uint32 type and tup is a struct. I want to convert it to go lang. I have decoded the struct but not able to figure out how to convert above line to go lang.

Comment: Translating between languages *requires* knowing both the old and new language well as well as the thing being translated. You should usually translate/port at higher than the statement level. In any case, either you know what that C does (in which case it should be easy-ish to port) or you don't, in which case you shouldn't be trying to port it.

Comment: I recommend reading this Go blog post https://blog.golang.org/strings because this is on place where Go is not very much like C imo.

Comment: Thanks @DaveC, I agree with you to a certain extent, but if I don't try how do I learn. Also I have been able to port most of it and this is kind of last thing that I need to get it done. I am not a master on both c or go, but have ability to read and make sense and write something new (with go).

Comment: @evanmcdonnal thanks for the link, I have read that, I know that char * is most probably a generic raw memory pointer used in place of void *, but want to confirm my understanding.

Comment: This is undefined behavior in C, unless the first element of the struct is an Oid (in which case there's no need for the pointer nonsense). What's the struct, and what are you trying to do? Probably there's a better way.

Comment: The string abstraction in Go simply doesn't allow for that. It intentionally will not allow you to take the address of an arbitrary index in a string. The reason I linked the article is because you should think about what piece of data you're trying to access and then assign it directly to a variable. Even if you find some way to arbitrarily point into a string in Go, it will be extremely questionable/hacky code.

Answer (score 0):

The Go equivalent to a casting a C pointer is converting a pointer to an `unsafe.Pointer`, which can then be converted to a pointer of any type you wish.

If `tup` is a pointer to a struct in C, you could convert it to a `*uint32` like so:

```
u := (*uint32)(unsafe.Pointer(C.tup))
```

Comment: Thanks @JimB, let me try that.